# I need help with plotting and SVEIAR Code with the Reproduction Number on Mathematica

Tags: plotting, fitting, scripting, mathematica-online

I need help because everytime I plot it doesn't work.

````
dS = q*lambda*N - (beta/N)*(h1*I + epsilon1*A)*S - z*S - mu*S;
dV = (1 - q)*lambda*N - (beta/N)*(h2*I + epsilon2*A)*V + z*S - mu*V;
dE = (beta/N)*(h1*I + epsilon1*A)*S + (beta/N)*(h2*I + epsilon2*A)*V -
    tau*E;
dI = rho*tau*E - mu*I - theta1*I;
dA = (1 - rho)*tau*E - mu*A - theta2*A;
dR = theta1*I + theta2*A - mu*R

(* Basic reproduction number R0 formula *)
R0Formula = Sqrt[(beta/N*(h1*I0 + epsilon1*A0)*(rho*tau + mu + theta1))/((z + mu)*(mu + theta2)*(mu + tau)*(mu + theta1 + tau))];```
````

Comment: Do you not have any values/range for the parameters?

Comment: What code did you use to plot? The letters `E`, `I`, and `N` should never be used for variables as they have pre-defined meanings in Mathematica. In general, user-defined variables should only use lower case letters for their first or only character to avoid potential naming conflicts with Mathematica's symbols.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.